# Error with creating an ifelse function

Tags: r

So this is my code right now, I'm trying to create a function that will detect the words  `"DRUG COURT"`

```
 drugcourt <- function(x) {
    ifelse(str_detect("DRUG COURT", print("TRUE"), print("FALSE")))
    }
```

And it's returning an error:

> unused argument (print("FALSE"))

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Missing a paren `ifelse(str_detect("DRUG COURT"), print("TRUE"), print("FALSE"))`
`

Comment: Also, str_detect probably should have `x` in it.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `ifelse` since `str_detect` returns a logical vector. Also note that `str_detect` needs two argumments: `string` and `pattern`, in your code you did not provide such a string.

```
drugcourt <- function(x) {
  stringr::str_detect(x, "DRUG COURT")
}

> x <- c("dog", "shark", "DRUG COURT")
> drugcourt(x)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can even replace `str_detect` and use `grepl("DRUG COURT", x)` an R base function.

Answer (score -1):

Remove print() - it's unnecessary in `ifelse()`

```
drugcourt <- function(x) {
  ifelse(str_detect(x, "DRUG COURT"), "TRUE", "FALSE")
}

drugcourt("HE WENT TO DRUG COURT")
# [1] "TRUE"
```